# sqlmetal fails to extract udf with full-text

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql, full-text-search

Error message:

```
Warning : SQM1014: Unable to extract function 'dbo.ProductFamilyIndex_EN' from SqlServer. Null or empty full-text predicate.
```

function defined as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ProductFamilyIndex_EN]
(   
    @topn int,
    @keywords nvarchar(4000)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    select top (@topn) ProductFamilyID 
    from (

        select pf.ProductFamilyID, t.[RANK] as _rank
        from containstable(ProductFamily, (Name_EN), @keywords, LANGUAGE 'English', @topn) t
        inner join ProductFamily pf on(pf.ProductFamilyID=t.[KEY])

        union all

        select p.ProductID as ProductFamilyID, t.[RANK] as _rank
        from containstable(Product, (LongDescription_EN, ShortDescription_EN), @keywords, LANGUAGE 'English', @topn) t
        inner join Product p on(p.ProductID=t.[KEY] and p.ProductFamilyID is null and p.Deleted is null)

    ) t
    group by ProductFamilyID
    order by max(_rank) desc
)
```

don't get confused by the union inside - that just means that a product without a family is a family on its own.

tried to give default values to the parameters:

```
@topn int = 1000,
@keywords nvarchar(4000) = 'test'
```

with the same result.

Using .NET 3.5 and sql2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Reposting my own answer properly so I can close this thread.*

Problem solved. 
Apparently sqlmetal runs the function to figure out the return type, but insists on supplying `null` parameter instead of `default`, which seems like sqlmetal's bug.
Way to work around it is to declare return type explicitly:

```
alter function [dbo].[ProductFamilyIndex_EN] (@topn int, @keywords nvarchar(4000))
returns @t table (ProductFamilyID int not null)
as begin
...
return end
```

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, SQLMetal needs a return type.

Another way to solve this, is to explicitly set your default inside the stored procedure:

`SET @topn = COALESCE(@topn, 1000)`

Throw that before the `SELECT` statement to insure that any NULL parameters will return a valid value.

This is useful not only for SQLMetal, but for anyone who uses this function.